# LaTeX says the package is not found but I do have the package installed [texlive] [linux mint] [texmaker]

Tags: packages, blindtext

I am using texmaker and texlive on my linux mint machine. I have just installed texmaker and texlive and when I try to

```
\usepackage{blindtext}
```

It says

> LaTeX Error: File blindtext.sty' not found

But I checked in 
`/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/blindtext` 
and there is the blindtext.sty file.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

*edit*: I should add I am pretty new to linux and have not gone too in depth into LaTeX yet so bear with me.

Comment: Make sure that your distro package manager has not installed another TeX Live into `/usr/share` or elsewhere. What does `which pdflatex` give, for example? My guess is you have 2 installations of TeX Live.

Comment: `which pdflatex` gives me `/usr/bin/pdflatex` but `whereis texlive` gives me `/usr/local/texlive /usr/share/texlive`

Comment: I deleted the whole `/usr/share/texlive` directory and it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: @Summer maybe making `mktexlsr` in terminal (or add `sudo` before)

Comment: you have installed the sources of a texlive 2016 but not set your PATH (to start something like `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/bin/linux_x64`  so you are picking up the pdflatex that came with yur operating system from /usr/bin/pdflatex and that probably uses a different tex input tree so will not look in   /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/

Comment: You really shouldn't delete files managed by your distro's package manager. You should uninstall them properly. You can install a dummy package so it knows you have TeX Live installed for dependency purposes.